# vcenter server on Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine

I am working with VMware and preparing a vcenter server on a Windows server. I would like to know, how good is vcenter in linux - has anyone tried it?

I would like to work with Ubuntu server, unless what someone suggests a better option.

Comment: What do you want to do with the ubuntu machine? A guest OS? A host OS?

Comment: i use the ubuntu server as a guest os, and i want to put vcenter there.

Answer (score 2):

VMWare is generally supported in linux, however if all your guests are linux, I'd recommend [LXC](http://lxc.sourceforge.net/).